# Is it called Drive-by Compromise if attacker provided his website for user to access?

Tags: attacks, system-compromise, mitre

If the website is legitimate and the attacker exploited that legitimate website, and the attacker gains access to a victim's system that visits the website, then it is a drive-by compromise.

However, if the attacker built the website, and the attacker gains access to a victim's system that visits the website, will it be called a drive-by compromise?

[Definition of drive-by compromise](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1189/)

Comment: No, what you are describing is called phishing.

Answer (score 1):

Both are types of Drive-By Compromise. It doesn't matter who owns the site. What matters is that the client is compromised by simply processing the malicious code delivered by the site.